# How to map within a for loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, array-map

We need to map an object array within a for loop, which actually works, but the editor is giving us a warning saying not to put a function within a loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.list.length; i++){
    $scope.data.list[i].isRowSelected=false;

    var pos1 = $scope.selectedItems.map(function(e) { return e.sys_id; }).indexOf($scope.data.list[i].sys_id);
    if(pos1!==-1){
        var add = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf($scope.data.list[i].sys_id);
        $scope.selectedItems.splice(add,1);
    }
}
```

To mitigate this, we're thinking about creating a separate function for the mapping and then calling it within the loop, like this:

```
function mappingID(e){
  return e.sys_id;
}
```

However, when we call upon it within the loop, we're lost as to what to pass in...any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `.map()` simply to search by `sys_id`?

Comment: hi Lex, yes, we're searching for sys_id within an object array and returning the entire object

Comment: Using `.map` in a loop like that might be expensive. Have you considered using a library like [LoDash](https://lodash.com/)? It makes searching collections really easy.

Comment: so outside the loop... `var  ids = $scope.selectedItems.map(function(e) { return e.sys_id; })` inside the loop `var pos1 = ids.indexOf($scope.data.list[i].sys_id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things, create a function outside the loop and avoid repeating indexing and object nesting. It will make your code much cleaner and easier to reason about.  I'm pretty sure this whole function could be done a lot better but I'm not sure of the bigger scope

```
var items = $scope.selectedItems;
var sys_id = function(e) { return e.sys_id; }
for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.list.length; i++){
    var data = $scope.data.list[i];  // might be a better name for this...
    data.isRowSelected=false;

    var pos1 = items.map(sys_id).indexOf(data.sys_id);
    if(pos1!==-1){
        var add = items.indexOf(data.sys_id);
        items.splice(add,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments suggest lodash, which is a good suggestion. For the purposes of your original question, however, you can declare the function `mappingID` as you have it, and simply put

```
var pos1 = $scope.selectedItems.map(mappingID).indexOf($scope.data.list[i].sys_id);
```

and that will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bring lodash to handle this, you can use `find`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.list.length; i++){
    $scope.data.list[i].isRowSelected=false;

    var item = $scope.selectedItems.find(e => (e.sys_id === $scope.data.list[i].sys_id));

    if (item) {
        $scope.selectedItems.splice(item,1);
    }
}
```

Also I suggest changing `selectedItems` to an plain-object/Map/Set so you can lookup in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing the same mapping on each iteration of the loop, move the mapping outside the loop:

```
var idArr = $scope.selectedItems.map(function(e) { return e.sys_id; })

$scope.data.list.forEach(item => {
    item.isRowSelected=false;

    var pos1 = idArr.indexOf(item.sys_id);
    if(pos1!==-1){
        var add = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item.sys_id);
        $scope.selectedItems.splice(add,1);
    }
})
```